# Call an expression from the isolated scope with & not working directly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm quite new to Angular, so I'm pretty sure there's something I'm missing here.
I just read an article about isolated scopes, with expressions in particular using & symbol.

This is the [article](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/), which includes a fiddle.

I'm trying to do something more simple, I want to use also a function but don´t want to use a button to do the calling, I'd like to directly call the function. I reduced the code in the fiddle to [something similar to what I want](http://jsfiddle.net/danaya/hohjnoc5/1/) but it has no effect, the function is not being called, or it is but is not doing what I expect.

If I uncomment line #12 I 'Hello' is displayed, and if comment then I expected 'as' to be displayed in the textbox, but instead it's cleared. What am I missing here?

Thanks,

PS. I can´t seem to make the snipped work, but the fiddle works fine.

```js
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
    .directive('myComponent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            isolatedExpressionFoo: '&'
        }
    };
})
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 'Hello!';
    //$scope.isolatedExpressionFoo();

    $scope.updateFoo = function () {
        $scope.foo = 'as';
    }
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="foo">
    <my-component isolated-expression-foo="updateFoo()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $scope from the controller and the directive are two different ones. The controller $scope has no access to the `isolatedExpressionFoo` function.

To instantly call the function provided to your directive (from within the directive) you will need to implement a controller for said directive.

E.g.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
    .directive('myComponent', function () {
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            scope:{
                isolatedExpressionFoo:'&'
            },
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.isolatedExpressionFoo();
            }
        };
    })
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.foo = 'Hello!';

        $scope.updateFoo = function () {
            $scope.foo = 'as';
        }
    }]);
```